# Always show the "Input" list when the "Sound" status bar icon is clicked

Tags: macos, audio, ui

The default behaviour of macOS is to show only the outputs when the "Sound" status bar is clicked.

I know that I can press the "Option" key to also show the "Input" list. But is there any way to make that the default behaviour?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?